# phpfastcache unlink() permission denied

Tags: php, unlink

I'm using phpfastcache https://github.com/khoaofgod/phpfastcache/

when I try to delete the cache I get an error

```
Warning: unlink(C:\...//sqlite/indexing): Permission denied in C:\...drivers\sqlite.php on line 328
```

I usually see that kind of error when there is a process not releasing the handle of those files.

Step to reproduce

```
// Require phpfastcache
require_once 'phpfastcache_v2.1_release\phpfastcache\phpfastcache.php';

// Simple singleton
class MyCache extends phpFastCache
{
    private static $istance;
    Private $obCache;

    function __construct()
    {
        $option = array('securityKey' => 'aCache', 'path' => dirname(__FILE__));
        $this->obCache = parent::__construct('sqlite', $option);
    }

    public static function getIstance()
    {
        if( is_null(self::$istance) )
        {
            self::$istance = new self();
        }

        return self::$istance;
    }
}




// check if cached
if( $CacheData = MyCache::getIstance()->get('aKeyword') )
{
    die('Cached');
}

// store in cache
MyCache::getIstance()->set('aKeyword','aValue', 60*60*24);

// clean cache (throw error)
MyCache::getIstance()->clean();

die('No cached');
```

this is the method of "phpfastcache" that generates the error

```
function driver_clean($option = array()) {
    // delete everything before reset indexing
    $dir = opendir($this->path);
    while($file = readdir($dir)) {
        if($file != "." && $file!="..") {
            unlink($this->path."/".$file);
        }
    }
}
```

does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm temporarily using @unlink()

I tried but nothing has changed

```
chmod($this->path."/".$file, 0777);
unlink($this->path."/".$file);
```

**UPDATE**

I'm under windows...

**UPDATE 2**

I installed XAMPP using the admin account, after installation run with admin privileges...

**UPDATE 3**

Solution:

```
function driver_clean($option = array()) {
    // close connection
    $this->instant = array();
    $this->indexing = NULL;

    // delete everything before reset indexing
    $dir = opendir($this->path);
    while($file = readdir($dir)) {
        if($file != "." && $file!="..") {
            unlink($this->path."/".$file);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on the environment that serves the script.

If it's CLI, the ability to creating, deleting or modifing files are controlled by the executing user.

If it's a PHP Stack ( WAMP, XAMPP, ZendServer or own Webserver+PHP+MySQL-Stack ) the executing layer ( apache, nginx ) must use an user which has rights to do what you want to do.

In both cases it depends on what you've configured or what had been inherited to your script, directory or drive.

Permission Knowledge could be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770962.aspx

Comment: I installed XAMPP using the admin account, after installation run with admin privileges...

Comment: a short hotfix would be granting "full access" for everybody to the file / directory. You've to investigate into your directory / application permission management for a more qualified solution.

Answer (score 1):

(Doesn't work under Windows) Try to change permissions before:

```
chmod($yourfile, '0777');
unlink($yourfile);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/chmod bool chmod ( string $filename , int $mode ) NOT chmod('0777', $yourfile). 
I tried but nothing has changed....

Comment: Hmmm under windows ... chmod is for Linux. My bad.